# Creating one unique file from many others saved in a folder

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list of csv files (approx. 100) that I'd like to include in one single csv file.
The list is found using

```
PATH_DATA_FOLDER = 'mypath/'


list_files = os.listdir(PATH_DATA_FOLDER)
for f in list_files:
            list_columns = list(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_DATA_FOLDER, f)).columns)
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns)
            print(df)
```

Which returns the files (it is just a sample, since I have 100 and more files):
['file1.csv', 'name2.csv', 'example.csv', '.DS_Store']

This, unfortunately, includes also hidden files, that I'd like to exclude.
Each file has the same columns:

```
Columns: [Name, Surname, Country]
```

I'd like to find a way to create one unique file with all these fields, plus information of the original file (e.g., adding a new column with the file name).

I've tried with

```
        df1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_DATA_FOLDER, f))
        df1['File'] = f # file name
        df = df.append(df1)
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates() # I'd like to drop duplicates in both Name and Surname
```

but it returns a dataframe with the last entry, so I guess the problem is in the for loop.
I hope you can provide some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

#drop duplicates and reset index
combined_csv.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

#Save the combined file
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using glob?

```
filenames = glob.glob("mypath/*.csv") #list of all you csv files.

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Surname", "Country"])
for filename in filenames:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Another way would be concatenating the csv files using the `cat` command after removing the headers and then read the concatenated csv file using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: it returns an empty dataframe when I print df. But in filenames there are all the csv files in that folder

Comment: Can you share the content of at least two of your files ?

Comment: It is just 10 and 14 distinct names, same for surnames. Country columns has only 4 distinct countries (US, UK, ES, GE)

Comment: I've forgotten the ```df=df.append(..)``` . I have edited the code in the answer.